# Using SO for code bugtracking & reporting: acceptable or not?

Tags: discussion

Just wondering about community "acceptable practice" here:  I've noticed that a few folks involved in building and releasing code packages for various languages (e.g. `Matlab` and `R` that I know of) started suggesting that bug reports be posted to SO rather than to some bugzilla-like site.  Is this an appropriate use of SO, or should SO remain "true" to its original goal of helping people through actual coding problems?

To clarify: I'm not asking why people shouldn't post questions about software bugs.  I'm asking whether the authors of software (typically opensource) should be discouraged from using (usurping?) SO as their bugtracker.     That's tangentially mentioned in some of the comments on the linked question,  but no solution is really presented.

Comment: The linked post applies equally well to Open Source projects as commercial companies, e.g. we won't vet if something is a valid bug in the project.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the link.   I guess I'm still concerned that there's no real answer other than applying peer pressure to folks who recommend bug reports be posted to SO>

Comment: Which is all we can do, really.

Comment: SO is not a bug tracker. If someone posts a known bug, or posts a hypothetical (and it's obvious the author already knows it's a bug), then sometimes you'll see comments like "This belongs on a bug tracker, not here."